# Pyspark: Split multiple array columns into rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has one row, and several columns. Some of the columns are single values, and others are lists. All list columns are the same length.  I want to split each list column into a separate row, while keeping any non-list column as is.

Sample DF:

```
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlc.createDataFrame([Row(a=1, b=[1,2,3],c=[7,8,9], d='foo')])
# +---+---------+---------+---+
# |  a|        b|        c|  d|
# +---+---------+---------+---+
# |  1|[1, 2, 3]|[7, 8, 9]|foo|
# +---+---------+---------+---+
```

What I want:

```
+---+---+----+------+
|  a|  b|  c |    d |
+---+---+----+------+
|  1|  1|  7 |  foo |
|  1|  2|  8 |  foo |
|  1|  3|  9 |  foo |
+---+---+----+------+
```

If I only had one list column, this would be easy by just doing an `explode`:

```
df_exploded = df.withColumn('b', explode('b'))
# >>> df_exploded.show()
# +---+---+---------+---+
# |  a|  b|        c|  d|
# +---+---+---------+---+
# |  1|  1|[7, 8, 9]|foo|
# |  1|  2|[7, 8, 9]|foo|
# |  1|  3|[7, 8, 9]|foo|
# +---+---+---------+---+
```

However, if I try to also `explode` the `c` column, I end up with a dataframe with a length the square of what I want:

```
df_exploded_again = df_exploded.withColumn('c', explode('c'))
# >>> df_exploded_again.show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|  d|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1|  1|  7|foo|
# |  1|  1|  8|foo|
# |  1|  1|  9|foo|
# |  1|  2|  7|foo|
# |  1|  2|  8|foo|
# |  1|  2|  9|foo|
# |  1|  3|  7|foo|
# |  1|  3|  8|foo|
# |  1|  3|  9|foo|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

What I want is - for each column, take the nth element of the array in that column and add that to a new row. I've tried mapping an explode accross all columns in the dataframe, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
df_split = df.rdd.map(lambda col: df.withColumn(col, explode(col))).toDF()
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**

You can replace `zip_` `udf` with `arrays_zip` function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip, col, explode

(df
    .withColumn("tmp", arrays_zip("b", "c"))
    .withColumn("tmp", explode("tmp"))
    .select("a", col("tmp.b"), col("tmp.c"), "d"))
```

**Spark < 2.4**

With `DataFrames` and UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StructField, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, explode

zip_ = udf(
  lambda x, y: list(zip(x, y)),
  ArrayType(StructType([
      # Adjust types to reflect data types
      StructField("first", IntegerType()),
      StructField("second", IntegerType())
  ]))
)

(df
    .withColumn("tmp", zip_("b", "c"))
    # UDF output cannot be directly passed to explode
    .withColumn("tmp", explode("tmp"))
    .select("a", col("tmp.first").alias("b"), col("tmp.second").alias("c"), "d"))
```

With `RDDs`:

```
(df
    .rdd
    .flatMap(lambda row: [(row.a, b, c, row.d) for b, c in zip(row.b, row.c)])
    .toDF(["a", "b", "c", "d"]))
```

Both solutions are inefficient due to Python communication overhead. If data size is fixed you can do something like this:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Length of array
n = 3

# For legacy Python you'll need a separate function
# in place of method accessor 
reduce(
    DataFrame.unionAll, 
    (df.select("a", col("b").getItem(i), col("c").getItem(i), "d")
        for i in range(n))
).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

or even:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, struct

# SQL level zip of arrays of known size
# followed by explode
tmp = explode(array(*[
    struct(col("b").getItem(i).alias("b"), col("c").getItem(i).alias("c"))
    for i in range(n)
]))

(df
    .withColumn("tmp", tmp)
    .select("a", col("tmp").getItem("b"), col("tmp").getItem("c"), "d"))
```

This should be significantly faster compared to UDF or RDD. Generalized to support an arbitrary number of columns:

```
# This uses keyword only arguments
# If you use legacy Python you'll have to change signature
# Body of the function can stay the same
def zip_and_explode(*colnames, n):
    return explode(array(*[
        struct(*[col(c).getItem(i).alias(c) for c in colnames])
        for i in range(n)
    ]))

df.withColumn("tmp", zip_and_explode("b", "c", n=3))
```

Comment: How can the solution for Spark >= 2.4 actually work? The documentation says that explode input "should be array or map type, not string", literaly quoting the exception it raises otherwise.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=explode#pyspark.sql.functions.explode

Comment: how do you handle uneven size list in different column..and requirement is to replace the  value as -1 for shorter size list.now it is is showing as null.

Comment: I got error "zip argument #1 must support iteration" when I run my code with StringType. What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 11):

You'd need to use `flatMap`, not `map` as you want to make multiple output rows out of each input row.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
def dualExplode(r):
    rowDict = r.asDict()
    bList = rowDict.pop('b')
    cList = rowDict.pop('c')
    for b,c in zip(bList, cList):
        newDict = dict(rowDict)
        newDict['b'] = b
        newDict['c'] = c
        yield Row(**newDict)

df_split = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd.flatMap(dualExplode))
```

Comment: if the first df has 3 values and second df has 2 values, our zip happens to be returning two pairs instead of 3. Could you advice on it.

Comment: Zip pairs together the first element of an obj with the 1st element of another object, 2nd with 2nd, etc until one of the objects runs out of elements. In your case, after 2 values. Said another way, it will pair up elements until there are no more items to pair. To give any suggestions, I'd need to know how you want your program to deal with the un-paired element (eg do you want a null from the 2nd set?). Also, there is only 1 df in this example. If your question is that different from this one, it's probably better to just ask another question

Comment: Thanks @David for your reply. I figured it out. Using Izip helped over to solve this issue. But still I appreciate your response mate.

Answer (score 7):

### One liner (for *Spark>=2.4.0*):

```
df.withColumn("bc", arrays_zip("b","c"))
  .select("a", explode("bc").alias("tbc"))
  .select("a", col"tbc.b", "tbc.c").show()
```

#### Import required:

`from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_zip`

---

### Steps -

1. Create a column bc which is an `array_zip` of columns `b` and `c`
2. Explode `bc` to get a struct `tbc`
3. Select the required columns `a`, `b` and `c` (all exploded as required).

### Output:

```
> df.withColumn("bc", arrays_zip("b","c")).select("a", explode("bc").alias("tbc")).select("a", "tbc.b", col("tbc.c")).show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  7|
|  1|  2|  8|
|  1|  3|  9|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps.DataFrame(df[['b','c']].pandas_api().iloc[0].to_dict()).to_spark()\
    .join(df[['a','d']],how='cross').show()
```

out:

```
+---+---+----+------+
|  a|  b|  c |    d |
+---+---+----+------+
|  1|  1|  7 |  foo |
|  1|  2|  8 |  foo |
|  1|  3|  9 |  foo |
+---+---+----+------+
```