# Pyspark UDF to return result similar to groupby().sum() between two columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following sample dataframe

```
fruit_list = ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple']
qty_list = [16, 2, 3, 1]
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame([(101, 'Mark', fruit_list, qty_list)], ['ID', 'name', 'fruit', 'qty'])
```

and I would like to create another column which contains a result similar to what I would achieve with a pandas `groupby('fruit').sum()`

```
        qty
fruits     
apple    19
orange    3
```

The above result could be stored in the new column in any form (either a string, dictionary, list of tuples...).

I've tried an approach similar to the following one which does not work

```
sum_cols = udf(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'fruits': x[0], 'qty': x[1]}).groupby('fruits').sum())
spark_df.withColumn('Result', sum_cols(F.struct('fruit', 'qty'))).show()
```

One example of result dataframe could be

```
+---+----+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| ID|name|               fruit|          qty|                   Result|
+---+----+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|101|Mark|[apple, apple, or...|[16, 2, 3, 1]|[(apple,19), (orange,3)] |
+---+----+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Do you have any suggestion on how I could achieve that?

Thanks

**Edit:** running on Spark 2.4.3

Comment: What is your desired output? It's unclear from the description, please show it explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your comment, done!

Comment: What version of spark? If it's spark 2.4+ you can use [`array_zip`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip). Older versions make this a little more difficult.

Comment: I'm running on 2.4.3 could you kindly provide me with an example usage for that in my case?

Comment: In my (limited) experience, I've seen "native" pyspark code perform 10x faster than UDFs (and especially UDAFs), even when an `explode` was being used. Just something to keep in mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a fancy way to do this using only the API functions on Spark 2.4+, perhaps with some combination of [`arrays_zip`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip) and [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate), but I can't think of any that don't involve an `explode` step followed by a `groupBy`. With that in mind, using a `udf` may actually be better for you in this case.

I think creating a `pandas` DataFrame just for the purpose of calling `.groupby().sum()` is overkill. Furthermore, even if you *did* do it that way, you'd need to convert the final output to a different data structure because a `udf` can't return a `pandas` DataFrame.

Here's one way with a `udf` using `collections.defaultdict`:

```python
from collections import defaultdict
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def sum_cols_func(frt, qty):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for x, y in zip(frt, map(int, qty)):
        d[x] += y
    return d.items()

sum_cols = udf(
    lambda x: sum_cols_func(*x),
    ArrayType(
        StructType([StructField("fruit", StringType()), StructField("qty", IntegerType())])
    )
)
```

Then call this by passing in the `fruit` and `qty` columns:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, col

spark_df.withColumn(
    "Result",
    sum_cols(array([col("fruit"), col("qty")]))
).show(truncate=False)
#+---+----+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+
#|ID |name|fruit                        |qty          |Result                    |
#+---+----+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+
#|101|Mark|[apple, apple, orange, apple]|[16, 2, 3, 1]|[[orange, 3], [apple, 19]]|
#+---+----+-----------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: I like your solution pault, thanks for your time. However I'm getting this error `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3564.showString....Caused by: net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)`.. does it tell you anything?

Comment: just added `from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, StructField`

Comment: Also try forcing Python int type as well in the output `return [(k, int(sum(v))) for k, v in d.items()]`, so that way the result of the udf will be definitely of Python native type.

Comment: @RichardNemeth that's a great point- which makes me wonder: are you sure you're using `__builtin__.sum` and not `numpy.sum` or `pyspark.sql.functions.sum`? [Why you shouldn't use `import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711135/5858851). **Edit** If you're getting a numpy object, it suggests that you're using `numpy.sum`.

Comment: yep Richard's solution seemed to solve the problem!

Comment: @crash I updated the answer to using a `defaultdict` of `int` instead of a `list`. that way you can do the sum inside the loop and avoid calling `sum` at the end. This should also fix your issue!

Comment: That's also cleaner! Thanks a lot @pault, this was extremely interesting and formative.

Answer (score 4):

As @pault mentioned, as of **Spark 2.4+**, you can use Spark SQL built-in function to handle your task, here is one way with **array_distinct** + **transform** + **aggregate**:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# set up data
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (101, 'Mark', ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'apple'], [16, 2, 3, 1])
      , (102, 'Twin', ['apple', 'banana', 'avocado', 'banana', 'avocado'], [5, 2, 11, 3, 1])
      , (103, 'Smith', ['avocado'], [10])
    ], ['ID', 'name', 'fruit', 'qty']
)

>>> spark_df.show(5,0)
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+
|ID |name |fruit                                    |qty             |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+
|101|Mark |[apple, apple, orange, apple]            |[16, 2, 3, 1]   |
|102|Twin |[apple, banana, avocado, banana, avocado]|[5, 2, 11, 3, 1]|
|103|Smith|[avocado]                                |[10]            |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+

>>> spark_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fruit: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- qty: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Set up the SQL statement:

```
stmt = '''
    transform(array_distinct(fruit), x -> (x, aggregate(
          transform(sequence(0,size(fruit)-1), i -> IF(fruit[i] = x, qty[i], 0))
        , 0
        , (y,z) -> int(y + z)
    ))) AS sum_fruit
'''

>>> spark_df.withColumn('sum_fruit', expr(stmt)).show(10,0)
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
|ID |name |fruit                                    |qty             |sum_fruit                               |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
|101|Mark |[apple, apple, orange, apple]            |[16, 2, 3, 1]   |[[apple, 19], [orange, 3]]              |
|102|Twin |[apple, banana, avocado, banana, avocado]|[5, 2, 11, 3, 1]|[[apple, 5], [banana, 5], [avocado, 12]]|
|103|Smith|[avocado]                                |[10]            |[[avocado, 10]]                         |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
```

### Explanation:

1. Use `array_distinct(fruit)` to find all distinct entries in the array `fruit`
2. transform this new array (with element `x`) from `x` to `(x, aggregate(..x..))`
3. the above function **aggregate(..x..)** takes the simple form of summing up all elements in array_T

   ```
   aggregate(array_T, 0, (y,z) -> y + z)
   ```

   where the **array_T** is from the following transformation:

   ```
   transform(sequence(0,size(fruit)-1), i -> IF(fruit[i] = x, qty[i], 0))
   ```

   which iterate through the array `fruit`, if the value of fruit[i] = x , then return the corresponding qty[i], otherwise return 0. for example for ID=101, when x = 'orange', it returns an array `[0, 0, 3, 0]`

Comment: wow that's a very nice answer thanks @jxc! Do you think this performs better than @pault solution?

Comment: @crash I would imagine this is better than using a `udf` +1

Comment: @pault, you're an experienced user, do you think this should be the accepted solution?

Comment: Yes, but it's your decision to make.

Answer (score 1):

If you have spark < 2.4, use the follwoing to explode (otherwise check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027315/pyspark-split-multiple-array-columns-into-rows/41027619)):

```
df_split = (spark_df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [(row.ID, row.name, f, q) for f, q in zip(row.fruit, row.qty)]).toDF(["ID", "name", "fruit", "qty"]))

df_split.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+------+---+
| ID|name| fruit|qty|
+---+----+------+---+
|101|Mark| apple| 16|
|101|Mark| apple|  2|
|101|Mark|orange|  3|
|101|Mark| apple|  1|
+---+----+------+---+
```

Then prepare the result you want. First find the aggregated dataframe:

```
df_aggregated = df_split.groupby('ID', 'fruit').agg(F.sum('qty').alias('qty'))
df_aggregated.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+---+
| ID| fruit|qty|
+---+------+---+
|101|orange|  3|
|101| apple| 19|
+---+------+---+
```

And finally change it to the desired format:

```
df_aggregated.groupby('ID').agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col('fruit'), F.col('qty'))).alias('Result')).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------------+
|ID |Result                    |
+---+--------------------------+
|101|[[orange, 3], [apple, 19]]|
+---+--------------------------+
```

Comment: `udf` likely has better performance than `explode` in this case

Comment: I do not know, but I changed the answer to `RDD` instead of explode.

Comment: I'm trying this out. I think distributing the code over multiple lines would help readability thou.

Comment: `udf` would almost surely (definitely?) be better than `rdd` as well

Comment: This works as well, but pault solution is much cleaner and easier to understand.