# reading a nested JSON file in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I'd like to create a pyspark dataframe from a json file in hdfs.

the json file has the following contet:

> {
>    "Product": {
>      "0": "Desktop Computer",
>      "1": "Tablet",
>      "2": "iPhone",
>      "3": "Laptop"
>    },
>    "Price": {
>      "0": 700,
>      "1": 250,
>      "2": 800,
>      "3": 1200
>    }
>   }

Then, I read this file using pyspark 2.4.4 `df = spark.read.json("/path/file.json")`

So, I get a result like this:

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
|Price                |Product                          |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
|[700, 250, 800, 1200]|[Desktop, Tablet, Iphone, Laptop]|
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
```

But I'd like a dataframe with the following structure:

```
+-------+--------+
|Price  |Product |
+-------+--------+
|700    |Desktop | 
|250    |Tablet  |
|800    |Iphone  |
|1200   |Laptop  |
+-------+--------+
```

How can I get a dataframe with the prevvious structure using pyspark?

I tried to use explode `df.select(explode("Price"))` but I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o688.select.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`Price`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<0:bigint,1:bigint,2:bigint,3:bigint>;;
'Project [explode(Price#107) AS List()]
+- LogicalRDD [Price#107, Product#108], false

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$transformExpressionsUp$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpression$1(QueryPlan.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$1(QueryPlan.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.mapExpressions(QueryPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1312)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-463397adf153> in <module>
----> 1 df.select(explode("Price"))

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in select(self, *cols)
   1200         [Row(name=u'Alice', age=12), Row(name=u'Bob', age=15)]
   1201         """
-> 1202         jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
   1203         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
   1204 

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
     68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'explode(`Price`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<0:bigint,1:bigint,2:bigint,3:bigint>;;\n'Project [explode(Price#107) AS List()]\n+- LogicalRDD [Price#107, Product#108], false\n"
```

Comment: Check accepted ans in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027315/pyspark-split-multiple-array-columns-into-rows

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Recreating your DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.json("./row.json") 
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- Price: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 0: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 1: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 2: long (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 3: long (nullable = true)
# |-- Product: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
# |    |-- 3: string (nullable = true)
```

As shown above in the `printSchema` output, your `Price` and `Product` columns are `struct`s. Thus `explode` will not work since it requires an `ArrayType` or `MapType`.

First, convert the `struct`s to `arrays` using the `.*` notation as shown in [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850490/5858851):

```
df = df.select(
    F.array(F.expr("Price.*")).alias("Price"),
    F.array(F.expr("Product.*")).alias("Product")
)

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- Price: array (nullable = false)
# |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
# |-- Product: array (nullable = false)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Now since you're using **Spark 2.4+**, you can use [`arrays_zip`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_zip) to zip the `Price` and `Product` arrays together, before using `explode`:

```
df.withColumn("price_product", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("Price", "Product")))\
    .select("price_product.Price", "price_product.Product")\
    .show()

#+-----+----------------+
#|Price|         Product|
#+-----+----------------+
#|  700|Desktop Computer|
#|  250|          Tablet|
#|  800|          iPhone|
#| 1200|          Laptop|
#+-----+----------------+
```

---

For older versions of Spark, before `arrays_zip`, you can explode each column separately and join the results back together:

```
df1 = df\
.withColumn("price_map", F.explode("Price"))\
.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
.drop("Price", "Product")

df2 = df\
.withColumn("product_map", F.explode("Product"))\
.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())\
.drop("Price", "Product")

df3 = df1.join(df2, "id", "outer").drop("id")

df3.show()

#+---------+----------------+
#|price_map|     product_map|
#+---------+----------------+
#|      700|Desktop Computer|
#|      250|          Tablet|
#|     1200|          Laptop|
#|      800|          iPhone|
#+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `concat_ws` + `split` - you're assuming the separator doesn't exist in the data. In any case, you can directly unpack the elements of the struct into an `array`, without enumerating each of them.

Comment: true ... that is where i was getting stuck ... how do you convert a nested ```struct``` to an ```array```?

Comment: Using `.*`: [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850490/5858851). For example: `df = df.select(array(expr("Price.*")).alias("Price"),   array(f.expr("Product.*")).alias("Product"))`. I think this followed by the `arrays_zip` is the way to go.

Comment: thanks! i agree ... very clean code ... it was the ```array``` function i was missing

Comment: the `id`s by monotonically_increasing_id() in df1 and df2 are problematic, they can easily out of sync on a large dataset. I suggest you create this id with `df = df.withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())` before creating df1 and df2.

Answer (score 3):

For Spark version without `array_zip`, we can also do this:

1. First read the json file into a DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df=spark.read.json("your_json_file.json")
df.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|Price                |Product                                   |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|[700, 250, 800, 1200]|[Desktop Computer, Tablet, iPhone, Laptop]|
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Next, expand the `struct` into `array`:

```
df = df.withColumn('prc_array', F.array(F.expr('Price.*')))
df = df.withColumn('prod_array', F.array(F.expr('Product.*')))
```

Then create a map between the two arrays

```
df = df.withColumn('prc_prod_map', F.map_from_arrays('prc_array', 'prod_array'))
df.select('prc_array', 'prod_array', 'prc_prod_map').show(truncate=False)


+---------------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|prc_array            |prod_array                                |prc_prod_map                                                           |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[700, 250, 800, 1200]|[Desktop Computer, Tablet, iPhone, Laptop]|[700 -> Desktop Computer, 250 -> Tablet, 800 -> iPhone, 1200 -> Laptop]|
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally, apply `explode` on the map:

```
df = df.select(F.explode('prc_prod_map').alias('prc', 'prod'))
df.show(truncate=False)

+----+----------------+
|prc |prod            |
+----+----------------+
|700 |Desktop Computer|
|250 |Tablet          |
|800 |iPhone          |
|1200|Laptop          |
+----+----------------+
```

This way, we avoid the potentially time consuming `join` operation on two tables.

Comment: This is a nice answer but it won't work if the keys are not unique or if any of the keys are null

Comment: Duplicate keys don't have any problem on mapping, null keys might be an issue here. May have to fill the missing values first.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using < 2.4.4
Then following gives answers.
However, for the strange schema of Json, I could not make it generic
In real life example, please create a better formed json

**PYSPARK VERSION**

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import Row
>>> json_df = spark.read.json("file.json") # File in current directory
>>> json_df.show(20,False) # We only have 1 Row with two StructType columns
    +---------------------+------------------------------------------+
    |Price                |Product                                   |
    +---------------------+------------------------------------------+
    |[700, 250, 800, 1200]|[Desktop Computer, Tablet, iPhone, Laptop]|
    +---------------------+------------------------------------------+
   >>> # We convert dataframe to Row and Zip two nested Rows Assuming there 
         #will be no gap in values
    >>> spark.createDataFrame(zip(json_df.first().__getitem__(0), json_df.first().__getitem__(1)), schema=["Price", "Product"]).show(20,False)

         +-----+----------------+
         |Price|Product         |
         +-----+----------------+
         |700  |Desktop Computer|
         |250  |Tablet          |
         |800  |iPhone          |
         |1200 |Laptop          |
         +-----+----------------+
```

**SCALA Version**( without preferred Case Class Method)

```
    scala> val sparkDf = spark.read.json("file.json")
sparkDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Price: struct<0: bigint, 1: bigint ... 2 more fields>, Product: struct<0: string, 1: string ... 2 more fields>]

scala> sparkDf.show(false)
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|Price                |Product                                   |
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
|[700, 250, 800, 1200]|[Desktop Computer, Tablet, iPhone, Laptop]|
+---------------------+------------------------------------------+
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> (sparkDf.first.getStruct(0).toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]], sparkDf.first.getStruct(1).toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]).zipped.toList.toDF("Price","Product")
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Price: bigint, Product: string]

scala> // We do same thing but able to use methods of Row  use Spark Implicits to get DataSet Directly

scala> (sparkDf.first.getStruct(0).toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Long]], sparkDf.first.getStruct(1).toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]).zipped.toList.toDF("Price","Product").show(false)
+-----+----------------+
|Price|Product         |
+-----+----------------+
|700  |Desktop Computer|
|250  |Tablet          |
|800  |iPhone          |
|1200 |Laptop          |
+-----+----------------+
```