# Reading nested Json structure in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to PySpark.I am trying to read  the values for one of the nested column of my JSON data.Here is my json structure:

```
-- _index: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _score: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- layers: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- R1.TEST6: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST1.idx: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST1.ide: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST3.PDU: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST3.pdu: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST4: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.agg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.size: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.start: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.beam: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.startIndex: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.regType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.coreSetType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.cpType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- R1.TEST2.column3: string (nullable = true)
```

As mentioned over the article,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811415/reading-a-nested-json-file-in-pyspark,I tried doing below:

```
df2 = df.select(F.array(F.expr("_source.*")).alias("Source"))
```

Now my requirement is to access the value that is under**R1.TEST6:  tag**

But below code is not working:

```
df2.withColumn("source_data", F.explode(F.arrays_zip("Source"))).select("source_data.Source.R1.TEST6.R1.TEST1.idx").show()
```

Can someone please help me on how can I access all the fields of this nested JSON and create a table as there are multiple levels of nesting present in this JSON **_source.R1.TEST6**
So how to use explode at this many multiple levels under

Comment: Try `df.select("_source.layers.``R1.TEST6``.``R1.TEST1``.*").show()`

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, thanks a lot we will try and let you know